# Storing long values in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, which stores info about a hex file. One of table rows is raw hex data of a chunk. Sometimes, it's longer(~90000) than DataGridViewTextBoxCell.MaxInputLength, and DataGridView don't want to let me store it in the cell. I am trying to avoid it by setting it to int.MaxValue, but it doesn't seem to work... The value of Cell simply don't display(But debug shows, that it's in there, successfully stored in the cell.) Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
if (s.Length >= ((DataGridViewTextBoxCell) this.datagridviewChunks.Rows[this.datagridviewChunks.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1]).MaxInputLength)
{
    ((DataGridViewTextBoxCell) this.datagridviewChunks.Rows[this.datagridviewChunks.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1]).MaxInputLength = int.MaxValue;
    ((DataGridViewTextBoxCell) this.datagridviewChunks.Rows[this.datagridviewChunks.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1]).Value = s;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be stored in the "model"?

Comment: You are refering to `DataGridViewTextBoxCell.MaxInputLength`, I guess.

Comment: try setting the max length to 999999999 that's the max length it can accept

Comment: I also added a question regarding the hard coded limit of *43679* characters [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355427/is-43679-a-magic-number).

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridViewCell` seems to have a maximum **43679** characters display limit, possibly because of a intended limitation due to the performance impact in rendering form controls. The value is stored inside the property, but is not shown.

I also found a SQL Server Management Studio related issue [SSMS - Can not paste more than 43679 characters from a column in Grid Mode](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode), probably because the `DataGridView` class is being used in the product.

I recommend you to use a separate `TextBox` instead on your form, which would show the value without any problem.

Comment: No, I need a excel-like table thingy. And btw, TextBox can't show what I want either - I want to put ~900000*1.5 symbols in there, but I can't.

Comment: Well, `~900000 * 1.5` is a quite large value compared to OP `~90000` when referring to the `TextBox.Text` content :)