# Is 43679 a magic number?

Tags: winforms, magic-numbers

Recently I was investigating this question: [Storing long values in DataGridView C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353785/storing-long-values-in-datagridview-c-sharp). After some tests I found out that the `DataGridViewCell` will not display any text with a length larger than **43679** characters, even if the value is actually stored in the cell and you can access it programmatically.

Actually, this has also been reported as a bug for `SQL Server Management Studio`: [SSMS - Can not paste more than 43679 characters from a column in Grid Mode](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode).

I guess that the limit is intended to prevent any overload on the UI rendering. But my questions are:

1. Why this exact value is being used?
2. Is there any documentation for this limit?

Comment: *divide by... no, multiply by.. maybe in hex, square root of.. carry the 1, no...someone's birthday* **NO IDEA.**

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759721/how-do-i-view-the-full-content-of-a-text-or-varcharmax-column-in-sql-server-20

Comment: Here's an archive.org mirror of the link by Alex filipovici's comment: "*The upper exclusive limit is **43680**, which is **10920** * **4**. A bug about a 10919 limit was linked to Vista by Microsoft: [SSMS : Grid will not display > 10.919 caharacters from VARBINARY(MAX)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130106182200/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/344117/ssms-grid-will-not-display-10-919-characters-from-varbinary-max).*"

Answer (score 5):

If convert `43679` to hex then it's `0xAAA0`. Or in inverse form `0xAAA0 = 0xFFFF - 0x555F`.

0x555F is code of Chinese Unicode symbol ['open; begin'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/555F/index.htm). May be it is a Chinese message or some kind of Chinese magic)