# SQL Server NText field limited to 43,679 characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, ntext

I working with SQL Server data base in order to store very long Unicode string. The field is from type 'ntext', which theoretically should be limit to 2^30 Unicode characters.

From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx):

> ntext
>
> Variable-length Unicode data with a maximum string length of 2^30 - 1 (1,073,741,823) bytes. Storage size, in bytes, is two times the string length that is entered. The ISO synonym for ntext is national
>   text.

*I'm made this test:*

1. Generate 50,000 characters string.
2. Run an Update SQL statement

   UPDATE [table]
   SET Response='... 50,000 character string...'
   WHERE ID='593BCBC0-EC1E-4850-93B0-3A9A9EB83123'
3. Check the result - what actually stored in the field at the end.

The result was that the field [Response] contain **only 43,679 characters**. All the characters at the end of the string was thrown out.

Why this happens? How I can fix this?

If this is really the capacity limit of this data type (ntext), which another data type can store longer Unicode string?

Comment: You should use Nvarchar(max) instead, but NText fields can hold much larger strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you view ALL text from an ntext or nvarchar(max) in SSMS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms)

Comment: Check @iceman825 solution. That was worked for me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709069/the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-textbox-can-display

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355427/is-43679-a-magic-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I've seen, you may just only be able to copy 43679 characters. It is storing all the characters, they're in the db(check this with Select Len(Reponse) From [table] Where... to verify this), and SSMS has problem copying more than when you go to look at the full data.

Comment: This was my problem solution. I was copying from the DBMS field, but I only got 43679 characters. Why? So I saved the ntext field from datatabase directly to the file and all characters were there. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`NTEXT` datatype is deprecated and you should use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

I see two possible explanations:

1. Your `ODBC` driver you use to connect to database truncate parameter value when it is too long (try using `SSMS`)
2. You write you generate your input string. I suspect you generate `CHAR(0)` which is **[`Null literal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828333/what-is-the-null-character-literal-in-tsql)**

If second is your case make sure you cannot generate `\0` char.

**EDIT:**

I don't know how you check the length but keep in mind that `LEN` does not count trailing whitespaces

```
SELECT LEN('aa     ')        AS length          -- 2
      ,DATALENGTH('aa     ') AS datalength      -- 7
```

Last possible solution I see you do sth like:

```
SELECT 'aa                aaaa' 

-- result in SSMS `aa aaaa`: so when you count you lose all multiple whitespaces
```

Check query below if returns **100k**:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(ntext_column)
```

Comment: 1) I'm running the SQL on "Sql Management Studio". 2) No Char(0) in the string - for sure.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Try `SELECT DATALENGTH(ntext_column)` if it returns 100k everything is ok

Comment: That is probably the limit for the management studio. What happens when you run the query from an odbc/ado connection?

Comment: I changed the NText to nVarChar(Max), tested with Entity Framework (C#) - now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

For all bytes; Grid result on right click and click save result to file.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm. The actual limit is 43679. Had a problem with a subscription service for a week now. Every data looked good, but it still gave us an error that one of the fields have invalid values, even tho, it got correct values in. It turned out that the parameters was stored in NText and it maxed out at 43679 characters. And because we cannot change the database design, we had to make 2 different subscriptions for the same thing and put half of the entities to the other one.