# SqlServer Management Studio - Edit Top 200 - Max length of fields

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've a table with an nvarchar(MAX) column containing text formatted as Json of various length, around 15000; 2 records have a length of 53000 in that column and these are not shown using the "Edit top 200" command, but are shown using a Select query in a standard window.

Is there a length limit on the columns that is possible to read and edit using the "Edit top 200" command in Sql server management? I'm pretty sure there's a limit, but I can't find references about that in the documentation and I'd also expect some message in the field, a placeholder like "your data is too long to be shown here". Having just the field empty could be a little bit confusing.
Sql server 14.0.2037; Management studio 15.0.18390.0

Thanks

Comment: You can try to install a latest version of SSMS v.18.10

Comment: Just don't use the "Edit Top *N*" feature, if I am honest. It's buggy and flaky. Use an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Max length looks to be `43,679` characters before it displays an empty string

Comment: Probably because it is a gridview https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355427/73226